# select user and all votes SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `users` table with fields user_id and username and I am querying it like so:

```
SELECT user_id, username FROM users WHERE user_id=$1
```

I also have a `votes` table that has fields post_id and user_id.
user_id is a foreign key referencing the user_id field in the users table.

I would like to add to my initial query to select all votes that are child votes of this user and have it all run in the same query. Maybe this needs to go into a separate query? I want to do it all at once to get the most accurate results, but I have not found a way...

Database is postgres btw.

**EDIT**
okay, first I tried both the inner join methods provided and neither worked if there were no votes.

Once there are votes and I am using some left outer full outer thing.. it returns a table like this:

```
 user_id | username | post_id 
---------+----------+---------
       6 | dbot77   |       3
       6 | dbot77   |       5
```

BUT IT RETURNS USELESS REPETITIVE INFORMATION

I just want, just out of my grasp...

```
 user_id | username | post_id 
---------+----------+---------
       6 | dbot77   |       3
         |          |       5
```

**OR EVEN BETTER**

```
 user_id | username | vote_post_ids 
---------+----------+---------
       6 | dbot77   |       [5, 3, etc.]
         |          |
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to get from the "votes" table? Number of votes cast by each user?

Comment: I want to get each vote row that references my user. my mom said this a very simple, so I feel embarrassed. please help

Comment: We will be doing you a disservice if we gave you the sql for this :-) you ought to read about inner join http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/

Comment: thanks for giving me a reference, I was getting overwhelmed trying the different solutions from the docs.. I am very new to sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this finally worked for me...

```
SELECT u.user_id
      ,u.username
      ,ARRAY(SELECT v.post_id FROM votes v WHERE v.user_id=u.user_id) AS votes 
FROM users u 
WHERE u.user_id=$1
```

it returned:

```
 user_id | username | votes 
---------+----------+-------
       6 | dbot77   | {3,5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.username, votes.column_name
FROM votes
INNER JOIN users
ON votes.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE votes.user_id = $1;
```

Refer to:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.username, votes.post_id
FROM users inner join votes on users.user_id = votes.user_id
WHERE users.user_id=$1
```